# extjs loading tree from json file using MVC

Tags: json, model-view-controller, extjs, tree, store

Hithere, I'm having a strange problem where when I load a tree from a json file it goes into a loop and displays the tree as follows (in a continous loop)

```
-A
  -A
    -A
      -A
```

My json

```
{
    "success": true,
    "results": [
        { "text": "number 1", "leaf": true },
        { "text": "number 2", "leaf": true },
        { "text": "number 3", "leaf": true },
        { "text": "number 4", "expanded": true, "children":[
            { "text": "number 4.1", "leaf": true },
            { "text": "number 4.2", "leaf": true },
            { "text": "number 4.3", "leaf": true }
        ]},
        { "text": "number 5", "leaf": true }
    ]
}
```

My model

```
Ext.define('App.model.TreeModel', {
    extend:'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
             { name: 'text', type: 'string'}
         ],

        proxy:{
            type:'ajax',
            url: 'data/tree.json',
            reader:{
                type:'json',
                root:'results'
            }
        }
    });
```

Store

```
Ext.define('App.store.MyTreeStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
    requires: 'App.model.TreeModel',
    model:'App.model.TreeModel',
});
```

View

```
Ext.define('App.view.MeetingTree', {
    extend:'Ext.tree.Panel',
    title:'Simple Tree',
    store:'MyTreeStore',
    alias:'widget.meetingtree',
    rootVisible:false,
    height:200
});
```

My init file

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'App', 
    autoCreateViewport: true,

    models: ['TreeModel'],    
    stores: ['MyTreeStore'],

    launch: function() {

    }
});
```

Dont have a clue why its looping.. anyone got an idea?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

finally found a solution

Remove the line

```
root:'results'
```

from the model

and star the json with

```
{ 
text: '.',
children: [{
```

full json

```
{ 
text: '.',
children: [{
    text:'Basic Ext Layouts',
    expanded: true,
    children:[{
        text:'Absolute',
        id:'absolute',
        leaf:true
    },{
        text:'Accordion',
        id:'accordion',
        leaf:true
    },{
        text:'Anchor',
        id:'anchor',
        leaf:true
    },{
        text:'Border',
        id:'border',
        leaf:true
    },{
        text:'Card (TabPanel)',
        id:'card-tabs',
        leaf:true
    },{
        text:'Card (Wizard)',
        id:'card-wizard',
        leaf:true
    },{
        text:'Column',
        id:'column',
        leaf:true
    },{
        text:'Fit',
        id:'fit',
        leaf:true
    },{
        text:'Table',
        id:'table',
        leaf:true
    },{
        text:'vBox',
        id:'vbox',
        leaf:true
    },{
        text:'hBox',
        id:'hbox',
        leaf:true
    }]
},{
    text:'Custom Layouts',
    children:[{
        text:'Center',
        id:'center',
        leaf:true
    }]
},{
    text:'Combination Examples',
    children:[{
        text:'Absolute Layout Form',
        id:'abs-form',
        leaf:true
    },{
        text:'Tabs with Nested Layouts',
        id:'tabs-nested-layouts',
        leaf:true
    }]
}]
}
```